# C# JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, end-to-end

I have a little problem with EndToEnd test in C#. It's my code from the Microsoft Site with examples of End-to-End tests.

```
var email = "mail1@testmail.com";
var response = await Client.GetAsync($"User/{email}");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDTO>(responseString);
Assert.Equal(email, user.Email);
```

After running program I got this exception. When I am debugging it - all works fine to the line with DeserializeObject. Can somebody gives me some link or tip how to handle this problem ?

Message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Error converting value 1 to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'id', line 1, position 167.
>   ---- System.ArgumentException : Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to System.Guid.

```
public class UserDTO 
{ 
public Guid Id { get; set; } 
public string Email { get; set; } 
public string Username { get; set; } 
public string FullName { get; set; } 
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: error is quite self describing, you have Guid in your DTO while the value is coming as integer

Comment: what's the value of `responseString` and definition of `UserDTO`

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to handle it, because i have never wrote End-to-end tests ;(

Comment: Show us the `UserDTO` model and the JSON data you're receiving.  Without them, your question can't be answered.

Comment: @MB_YD There is an Edit link below the question.  Paste your code there, not in a comment.

Comment: "{\"result\":{\"id\":\"0559d01d-938a-4155-b9c6-91337e631e62\",\"email\":\"mail1@gmail.com\",\"username\":\"name\",\"fullName\":null,\"createdAt\":\"2018-08-29T17:12:11.9145255Z\"},\"id\":39,\"exception\":null,\"status\":5,\"isCanceled\":false,\"isCompleted\":true,\"isCompletedSuccessfully\":true,\"creationOptions\":0,\"asyncState\":null,\"isFaulted\":false}"

Comment: It looks like the endpoint you’re hitting is forgetting to `await` a `Task`. Include the code for the endpoint itself if possible so that can be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Per your posted json string Change the `public Guid Id { get; set; }` property to probably `public string Id { get; set; }` in `UserDTO`

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use [`Guid.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to convert that string to GUID

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDTO>(responseString);
Guid newGuid = Guid.Parse(user.id);
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to use Guid, to have unique Id for users.

Comment: @MB_YD Sequential Guid?  If not make sure you avoid using this for the PK/Clustered Index on your table in that case.  Kimberly Tripp explains this very well:  https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/